# How to add new Price field in VirtueMart admin panel Product pricing

Tags: joomla, virtuemart

**Joomla 3.6.5 , VirtueMart 3.0.18**

i was wondering if any developer can give me an idea? Any help would be really appreciated!

My client according to his needs want in the **admin panel** to add one more input box field that will have the **Catalogue Price** of a product. Please dont ask the why..

1.This field will be saved in the **jos_virtuemart_product_prices** table in a new column named **catalog_price decimal(15,2)**

2. **This field will be independent from any calc-tax rule, ;)** ,, the price that is inserted in this field in the back exaclty this will be inserted in the jos_virtuemart_product_prices table in the new column catalog_price
3. **the aim is that This field will be shown in the front in the place of deleted price with tax**

So far i have done the following,

1. done the new column catalog_price decimal(15,2) in the jos_virtuemart_product_prices table
2. done the new input box that holds the new catalogue price in the admin panel in the

administrator\components\com_virtuemart\views\product\tmpl\product_edit_price.php

and next step is that i want to save that price in the db ... where **is the save-submit class??function??post method??** i m confused!! :-[ :-[ please some help guys!!

thank you in advance

Comment: I'm working on it. I will update you as i will get finished!

Comment: just finished after 2 hrs of "hit and try"

Comment: BTW.. add custom fields, because that work in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Use Custom Fields, those work in the same way but still if you need, follow the following method.

I've a similar kind of request. I am required to add new fields to show some YouTube videos related to products.

What I did was:

**New Fields in Database Table**

Alter the database table where we need to add new field.
What I had to do is, I need some custom information for some products like YouTube videos, or some other downloadable content etc. so created a field `product_youtube_link | varchar=128` in table

**abcd_virtuemart_products** (here abcd is my pre-title for tables)

**Showing Table Field in VM Admin's Front End**

in to following page (because I wanted to show this field in backend/Admin view under product->custom fields).

```
  website/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/views/product/tmpl/product_edit_custom.php
```

I added following line of code:

```
<fieldset style="background-color:#F9F9F9;">
    <legend>Installation Guide</legend>
    YouTube URL like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwgLvK830xI 
    <div style="width: auto;">
        <input type="text" size="40" name="product_youtube_link" id="product_youtube_link" value="<?php echo $this->product->product_youtube_link; ?>" />
    </div>
 </fieldset>
```

This will show an input filed under product->custom fields - in Virtuemart 3.x.x

So far now, it doesn't show any values from database (I added manually something in phpMyAdmin for one specific product).

To make this field readable and editable or deletable we have to do a lot of work.  :)

Don't be scared. That is the simplest work:

In the following file.

```
website/administrator/components/com_virtuemart/helpers/shopfunctions.php
```

and found a function `getValidProductFilterArray() ...` on line 980 . and added database field title at the end of $filterArray's values.

This array should end now:

**before**

.....'pc.ordering');

**after**

.....'pc.ordering', '**product_youtube_link**');

Now refreshed the product view in VM administrator panel.  And wow, my database values are there (what I manually added)

To test if that value is actually working. I changed this value on the front end in product view in VM Administrator panel. Saved that product, and that value updated. I opened phpMyAdmin, and that was updated.

**How to show this value on front end of website.**

I need to show this under product details.

because I'm using template overrides. so under

```
website/templates/mytemplate/html/com_virtuemart/productdetails/default.php
```

or if using no overrides then in defualt template details page for vm..

```
website/components/com_virtuemart/views/productdetails/tmpl/default.php
```

I added following lines

```
<?
if (!empty($this->product->product_youtube_link)) {
    echo $this->product->product_youtube_link;
  } 
?>
```

And that data is appearing on front end.